# setState does not cause children to update

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a fairly simple application with react, socket.io, and react-apexcharts (or any other charting library for that matter).
I'm pretty sure i understood the concept of states well enough - I'm not new to programming, but, i can't seem to understand what the problem is.
I have a simple react component:

```
export default class NumberCandleStickChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            options: {
              chart: {
                id: "number-candlestick",
              },
            },
            series: props.series,
            a: props.a
          };

    }        
    render(){
        return (
            <>
            <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.a)}</p>
            <Chart
              options={this.state.options}
              series={this.state.series}
              type="candlestick"
              width="500"
            />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

And it is used like that:

```
//imports
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = openSocket('http://localhost:4200');

    this.state = {
      connected: false,
      interval: '10s',
      series: [{
        name: "numbers",
        data: []
      }]
    }

    this.handleNumberIn = this.handleNumberIn.bind(this);    
     this.socket.on('newNumber', this.handleNumberIn)
  }

  handleNumberIn(input) {
    const newSeries = [...this.state.series];
    input.data.map(//map to correct format and push to newSeries);
    this.setState({
      series: newSeries
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>
            {this.state.connected.toString()}
          </p>
          <NumberCandleStickChart series={this.state.series} a={this.state.series} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, a prop is there to let me see if the state actually changes, and it does, it adds data to the array correctly, according to the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/).
I tried emulating the same with setInterval, and the same happens, and i tried a different charts library, and still no luck - so i am assuming i am doing something not right.
App was created using the create-react-app boilerplate - nothing more.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It will be easier for people reading your question if you clean up the code, offering a minimal reproduction of the problem. It's hard to identify relevant parts when there's `console.log` and input handlers, etc. The act of trying to create that example may very well lead you to a solution, too.

Comment: You are using props in you subcomponent only during the initial render. When props change, you are not updating your state. Why dont you use props directly?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `handleNumberIn`. It should be:

```
handleNumberIn(input) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    series: [...prevState.series, input.data.map(/* your map function */)],
  }));
}
```

Specifically, `Array.prototype.map()` returns a new array with the mapped data, it does not modify the existing one.

Comment: The map function is fine, im mapping them to the correct format and pushing them to a new array, the problem isn't there as i stated in my question.

Comment: `map` is not what you want to use to iterate over an array and do arbitrary operations (such as adding it to another list). you'd use a regular `for` or `for...of` loop, or the `forEach` method. `map` is meant for taking an array of `x` and returning an array of `y` based on the functor you supply.

Comment: upvoted. this is the only way series can be visually updated after construct

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor method of NumberCandleStickChart , the lines

```
series: props.series
a: props.a
```

are invoked only once.Whenever the state in App.js updates ,the new props received by NumberCandleStickChart are not mapped to its state again.

You do not need the this.state.series in NumberCandleStickChart.You could directly use

```
<Chart
    options={this.state.options}
    series={this.props.series}
    type="candlestick"
    width="500"
 />
```

You could do the same for this.state.a

Comment: Wish that was the problem, but it made no difference.
And if that was the case, why does this.state.a re-renders fine?

Comment: Does it rerender with the new value of this.state.a .i.e the updated array?

Comment: Indeed it does, it shows the array in the correct format.

Comment: That's quite strange.In that case,the last thing that comes to my mind is adding a key prop ...something like  <Chart  key = {JSON.stringify(a)} /> alongwith all the other props.

Comment: It fixed it! could you explain why that fixes it? and let me accept your answer !

Comment: Great ! React needs an element's unique identity for its virtual dom to identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.The JSON.stringify(a) would always provide a unique string representation of the updated array which would cause the <Chart /> component to rerender. I have generally faced this issue in dealing with arrays.